# Salesforce packaging Error with no proper explanation

Tags: salesforcedx, package, unmanaged-package

I am trying to create a package version and I started getting a error, which gives me no hints to what the problem is.

```
packageVersionCreateResult = {
    "code": 1,
      "context": "PackageVersionCreateCommand",
      "commandName": "PackageVersionCreateCommand",
      "message": "Multiple errors occurred: \n(1) An unexpected error occurred. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 825679285-57767 (-258088949)",
    "name": "MultipleErrorsError",
    "status": 1,
    "stack": "MultipleErrorsError: Multiple errors occurred: 
                (1) An unexpected error occurred. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 825679285-57767 (-258088949)
                    at Messages.createError (/root/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/messages.js:393:16)
                    at PackageVersionCreateCommand.run (/root/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-packaging/lib/commands/package/version/create.js:79:32)
                    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
                    at async PackageVersionCreateCommand._run (/root/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js:117:22)
                    at async Config.runCommand (/workspace/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js:329:25)
                    at async run (/workspace/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/main.js:89:16)",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "warnings": []
}
```

I tried changing API versions, I tried different versions of sfdx/sf CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Stacktrace id, `-258088949`, I've checked our Salesforce internal logs and see the error message is `java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor`.

The error is caused by the zero-length contents in the zip file. Here is the JDK bug [JDK-8143613](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8143613) This is something that Oracle should fix in the JDK.

For the package version creation, the zip file is created by the sfdx command. The workaround is one of them,

- Remove the zero-length file
- Add some contents to the zero-length file

Comment: I tried searching for the same code, and found nothing, ... but this actually makes some sense. The issue turned out to be an email template without any content.
However, what still confuses me is that that email template is not part of the package, but unpackaged metadata. It should not affect it

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal Salesforce error. There are three options for debugging these:

1. Contact Salesforce Support. They are the only ones who can find out why the error was triggered.
2. Search the internet for the second number (-258088949). This is unique to this particular error. So if someone else has asked online and solved it, or has contacted Salesforce Support and got an answer, then this can help you fix the error without having to contact support yourself.
3. Check your codebase for anything that looks like it might cause issues. (I get this is a pretty subjective measure!) If you share more of your code here, we might be able to spot potential issues.

Unfortunately I can't find any reference to that error online, so your best bet is Salesforce support.